# How do I use JQuery to move the user's screen down to the bottom, in a very smooth way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have a long page of text. The user is browsing at the top.

How can I move the user all the way to the bottom of the page, in a smooth way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.scrollto() is what you're looking for.

[**Here's an example**](http://www.tympanus.net/scrollupdown/) of exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I barely saw the little transparent-while-scrolling arrows on the bottom left while I was scrolling around and clicking on anchors :P

Comment: How do I add easing into that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into scrollTo and animation?

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

This can be adapted to scroll to the bottom of the page.